# PHP Insert array into multidimensional array is overwrite

Tags: php, arrays

I´m trying to insert arrays into other array, the problem is that when I call the array_push() method it overwrites the last one element of my array, then I just get an array with data of one array (the last one):

```
  $users_data = [];
    $resultSize = count($result); 

    $data = $result; 

    for ($i = 0; $i < $resultSize; $i++) {
        $person = [
            'nombre'         => $result[$i]['nombre'],
            'apellido'       => $result[$i]['apellido'],
        ];
        array_push($users_data, $person);
        // $users_data = $person; I also have tried with this method. 
    };
```

I just receive one object with this:

```
 Object {nombre: jane, apellido: doe}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shud be like this,

```
$person['nombre'][$i] = $result[$i]['nombre'];
$person['apellido'][$i] = $result[$i]['apellido'];
                   ^ you have missed this index.
```

Then no need of `array_push()`. you can directly assign `persons` to `user_data`

Comment: @LeonardoCavani consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I needed 8 minutes to do it XD. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Or like this :

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $resultSize; $i++) {
    $users_data['nombre'][] = $result[$i]['nombre'];
    $users_data['apellido'][] = $result[$i]['apellido'];
};
```